# Add bootstrap button to rewrite output views

Tags: views, theming

I have a view with a table, the last column is a link but should be a button.
So in the last field i enable rewrite output and add this code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      [clone_node] 
</button>
```

I am using the bootstrap theme. But views is filtering out the button code.
What is the fasted way to change the link into a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not be what you need, but in Bootstrap you can create buttons using the `<a>` anchor, which will not be filtered out by Views.

```
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
        [clone_node] 
  </a>
```

Comment: Thanks that works on some fields. But not this field. 
Views outputs this as:<a 


       href="/node/1/clone/GWuOFvCfNwMpz182dJajjHoqOsFeAYS29YRzgHb248k?node-clone-destination=subco-overzicht"></a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
        dupliceren 
  </a>

Comment: I found this works by placing a button even when using the same classes, and closing with the </a> tag instead of </button>

Comment: Thanks @Will, you are completely right! The </button> closing tag was of course wrong. I have just corrected it.